# Tomcat - Sharing static content between multiple Spring Security applications

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-security, spring-boot

I deployed multiple applications (Spring Boot with Spring Security) in Tomcat which share same static content (html, css, images).
To avoid the need of redeploying each application when I update a css or html file, I put all static content into a separate folder on the server and configured **server.xml** like so:

```
<Host appBase="webapps"
           autoDeploy="false" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true"
           xmlNamespaceAware="false" xmlValidation="false">
    ...
    <Context docBase="/home/stuff" path="/" />

  </Host>
```

This works perfectly fine, but the problem is I'm using `Spring Security` to secure my applications. Before, when all static content was included in each application, I was getting a login screen when accessing my application, now, after I moved all static content into a separate folder I don't get the the login screen anymore, since all static content can be accessed directly.

What should I do to trigger the Authentication even when accessing a static content?

Or is there a better way in this situation, where I have multiple applications which share same static content and I don't want to redeploy all of them when I need to add a new line into the css file?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the re-deploys.  Set yourself up with a good CI server (Jenkins, Travis, etc.) and let it handle the deployments for you.

Comment: you can treat your static content just like another one web app (war). and work with it correspondingly - deploy, secure, refer from other apps, etc...